# How to remove row from excel using Python/PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, excel, key, delete-row, pysimplegui

Dears,

How to remove row from excel using Python/PySimpleGUI.
Knowing that I'm using the reverse process of adding rows to excel file using PySimple :

Add Row :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

..........
[sg.Button('Submit', size=(6, 1), button_color=('White','Dark'))]


if event == 'Submit':
    new_record = pd.DataFrame(values, index=[0])
    df = pd.concat([df, new_record], ignore_index=True)
    df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
    sg.popup('Data Saved!', font=("Helvetica", 11),text_color='Yellow', no_titlebar=True, button_type=5)
    clear_input()
```

And for deleting row with a given key , i'm using the following code and didn't help :

```
   if event == 'Delete':
    df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)
    df = df[df.Column1!= 'ENTRY']
    df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
    sg.popup('Entry Deleted!')
```

Could you please advice ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you drop the column from the df and then rewrite to excel if needed?

`df = df.drop(['rowToDelete'])`

Comment: Thanks @Virt, I add your recommendation, unfortunately didn't help, I got the following error :     df = df.drop[df.Column1!='ENTRY']
         ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Hi again, just to clarify little bit more, I'm using the following topic :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svcv8uub0D0 ,  to create an excel form using python, and since the program is creating duplicate enteries with same value in 1st column and not checking what is inside, so I want to find a way to check if this entery is already exists, than I will delete it ( in case I want to change data inside ) or use another method for updating same entery instead of creating a duplicate one. Hope you got my point . Thx

Comment: @Jason Yang, Could you please help on this topic? Thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone can help on this topic?